# Request sql on an Oracle server always empty. c#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, select, reader

when i trying the same query on Oracle SQL develloper:

```
select nom_projet from analyses where nom_projet='demonstration';
```

it works, so i very don't know where could come the error...
I think it's due to the format of my request but i don't see the error.

Code C#

```
public Boolean VerifierVersionDejaPresnte(ParseurXML.DonneesGlobales donneGlobale)
    {
        string sql = "select nom_projet from analyses where nom_projet = :nom_projet" ;
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OracleParameter p_nom_projet = new OracleParameter();
        p_nom_projet.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        p_nom_projet.Value = donneGlobale._nomProjet;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_nom_projet);

        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(dr.Read())
             Console.WriteLine(dr.GetString(0));
        return (true);

    }
```

Thank you in advance for you help

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that the query returns no data, so `dr.Read()` returns false. You should always check the result of `dr.Read()` before trying to access the data.

```
if (dr.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(dr.GetString(0));
}
```

Of course, it doesn't completely solve the issue... now you must find why the query returns nothing.